# Android decode ImageFile to Bitmap using JNI

Tags: android, bitmap, java-native-interface

I am trying to decode imageFile into bitmap using JNI in android. Is there any sample code to decode imageFile into bitmap, otherwise the sample code to decode  byteArray to Bitmap is also welcome using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the android source code. for the android os decode it with JNI.